# Developing Android trivia quiz game

Tags: java, android

Hi i am Beginner in Android and Java OOP..I am currently building Android quiz game. The application should display 6 questions with 4 answers, if the player's answer is correct then player will score 5 points and move to another question, if player answer the incorrec question player scores no point but will move to different question, feedback to the player should be provided as well (im planning to use Toast for this one). In the end, player will get to the final screen to see the total score and correct answer.. Now, I am not sure how to display the 6 Questions and 4 answers by using ArrayList? the questions and answers also should be stored in file (im not planning to use SQLdbhelper)

i am new with quiz/trivia game before.here is what i have done so far:

```
public class play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private int totalcorrectanswers;
private int correctanswers;
private Random random;
private TextView questiontextview;
private int score;
private int finalscore;


Button answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4;
Button AnswerButtons [] = {answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4};



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play);

        View AnswerButton1 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton1);
        AnswerButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        View AnswerButton2 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton2);
        AnswerButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        View AnswerButton3 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton3);
        AnswerButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
        View AnswerButton4 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton4);
        AnswerButton4.setOnClickListener(this);



    }
```

XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity = "center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scorenumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerbutton1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerbutton2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerbutton3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerbutton4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` to persist for the answers to the end of a cycle to see how many were answered correct. Now for the questions if you do not think of bd at the moment, you can use the strings file to organize the questions!

Comment: @André.C.S No, SharedPreferences are for settings, not to store program data.

Comment: You should use `SQLdbhelper`, it's what it is for.

Comment: Actually `SharedPreferences` is now used for various purposes, very used to persist simple data structure, the internet has countless exemple using `SharedPreferences` couple other purposes besides storing configuration values​​. see it [Quiz App Tutorial (Shared Preferences Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOThNfYv-uI)

Comment: So where are you storing the questions and answers, if not in SQLite? Files? I guess you *can* use an XML structure for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you create one model for question and answer (show below class).

```
public class MyQuestion {

private String question;
private ArrayList<String> ans;

public MyQuestion(String question, ArrayList<String> ans) {
    this.question = question;
    this.ans = ans;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAns() {
    return ans;
}
```

}

after that for your question and answer create one static arraylist. First time your arraylist is empty then add your question and answer.Next time your arraylist is with questions and answers.

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

static ArrayList<MyQuestion> myQuestions = new ArrayList<MyQuestion>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (myQuestions.isEmpty()) {
        addQuestionAndAnswer();
    }

}

private void addQuestionAndAnswer() {
    // here add your question and answer
}
```

}

Comment: are you sure about that static list?

Comment: @Zhuinden I think yes, because of this list only one time create when app open first time. And second thing in this app only 6 question. If more question then its not work.

Comment: @Divyang Hey thanks! :) but im getting an error on protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     because it has to implement super type method.

Comment: @user3829911 edited my answer please check. If any problem then tell me.

Comment: @Diyang hey thanks :) sorry forgot to ask, does this mean i have to use ListView? i just edited my question. u can see my XML file now.

Comment: @user3829911 hi, not use list view, In your question and answer layout Set One textview for Question and already you have 4 buttons for answer. If User press any answer button is correct or incorrect move to next question from Question Arraylist and set Question and Answer. Understand or not ??